# Making a list of tuples (where each tuple contains two numpy arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I am looking to build a training set that mimics the MNIST handwriting set. Specifically, the training set is a list of tuples in the form:

```
example_tuple = (np.array([[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.]], dtype=np.float32), np.array([[0.],[0.]]))
```

I cycle through a for-loop creating a new tuple of the same shape and would like to append it to the first tuple such that the result is a list type. Of course tuples cannot be appended so I am unsure to create a list of tuples containing two numpy arrays each.

Ideally the final form of the training data would look something like:

```
[(array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.]])), (array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32), array([[1.],
       [1.]]))]
```

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide to help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a list of lists, then you can simply convert it to a list of tuples like this:

```
[tuple(v) for v in list_of_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create the tuples, and append them to a list.  This produces your desired result:

```
In [31]: alist=[]
In [32]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     tup = np.ones((5,1))*i, np.ones((2,1))*i
    ...:     alist.append(tup)
    ...:     
In [33]: alist
Out[33]: 
[(array([[ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.],
         [ 0.]]), array([[ 0.],
         [ 0.]])), (array([[ 1.],
         [ 1.],
         [ 1.],
         [ 1.],
         [ 1.]]), array([[ 1.],
         [ 1.]])), (array([[ 2.],
         [ 2.],
         [ 2.],
         [ 2.],
         [ 2.]]), array([[ 2.],
         [ 2.]]))]
```

While you can't `append` to a tuple, you can concatenate two of them, e.g. `alist[0]+alist[1]`, but that creates a 4 element tuple, which I don't think you want.  Your target just appears to be a list of tuples.